# Manipulating SQLite when programming Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am a Android Developer and I Have used Intellij IDEA to programming Java and there is a Database Tab to manipulate the data base. Now I am using Android Studio v0.8.14 and there is not a Tab for database.

I would like to know what is the best way, best practice or the best DBMS to use when programming for Android to manipulate SQLite.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the SQLite Manager addon for FireFox to create, edit and query a SQLite db.

Comment: SGDB? you mean DBMS?

Comment: you have to install third party eclipse plugin. Or if you are using  an emulator for development you can export your db to your desktop for checking the db. goto data/data/your_package_name/databases/yourdb.db

Comment: Sorry is the acronym for my language, I'm editing the post, thanks.